# Apple Store Server Notification: Python OpenSSL certificate loading fails in "header too long"

Tags: python, django, cryptography, decoding

On my django server, I'm trying to decode the JWT content sent by the Apple Store Server Notification using Apple's package `app-store-server-library-python`.

Under the [official documentation](https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-python), when starting to do the verification and decoding, we find this line:

```
root_certificates = load_root_certificates()
```

The implementation is not provided unfortunately. By looking here and there, I've tried several implementations that always fail in :

> OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', '', 'header too
> long')]

Here is my implementation:

```
def load_root_certificates():
    in_file = open("AppleRootCA-G3.cer", "rb")
    data = in_file.read()
    in_file.close()
    return load_certificate(FILETYPE_ASN1, data)
```

What could be the cause of the issue here?
Thanks for the help!